# Sketch with Dropbox and multiple users

Tags: dropbox, sketchapp

I am using Bohemian Coding Sketch to design websites. All my files are in Dropbox, shared with a team (another designer). Most of the time we are working together with same files — one is editing, another is watching and discussing. I think this is a pretty common scenario these days.

When files are changed by the other, they get changed on my disk by Dropbox. And after that things go worse. Sketch gives this warning:

[image]

Any choice I make is bad, because:

1. Revert changes. It does not mean "revert to a file on disk". It actually means "revert to a file state, that was when you last opened the file".
2. Save. Means "overwrite with your changes work from other designer".
3. Cancel. Means "Do nothing"

Since this dialog opens when I close the Sketch, I have no option, but to shoot myself in a foot.

Does someone have a solution? One proposed is to copy files from shared folders to view them, which works but smells funky...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So this is a workflow issue. Sketch doesn't have or offer the ability of multiple user versioning. So it's a highly bad idea for more than one person to be working on the same file.

You're two choices are...

1. Have the other artist create a duplicate file. Not only does this insure proper versioning (something you guys should be keeping track of), but it also allows for the lead to then take the best ideas from each and combine them into a new versioned file.
2. Purchase an asset management system like AlienBrain. It handles a lot of the tedious processes of versioning for multiple artists in a studio. However I'm not aware of its integration with DropBox.

Comment: I don't ask Sketch to have multiple user versioning. Dropbox as well as many other tools has already solved this task. They just have to accept the fact, that people do use this software in multiple user scenarios.

Duplicate files is an ugly workaround, which is... working. Just a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Correct. However right now that's totally not possible.

Comment: Other software (actually any software on my Mac) is doing just fine — all Adobe stack, all developer tools. Just not Sketch.

Comment: I faced this issue too at work. I partially solved using Brand.ai. Is a plugin that allow to share symbols, assets, text style and whatever is possible to do on Sketch in Cloud with whoever you want. Just download it and give it a try. For me it was a life-saver. BTW you have to duplicate the file, but if you change something (ex. a symbol that is used by your colleague in his file) you can upload it in Brand.ai and let him syncing his file with your new symbol.